# Последовательная загрузка картинок через ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я получаю массив id картинок, а потом последовательно загружаю картинки по id.
но аякс асинхронный и первая картинка вставляется та,которая первая скачается.
а если я выключаю асинхрон то картинки вставляются только когда загрузится ПОСЛЕДНЯЯ.
как мне сделать вот чтобы они загружались поочередно?

Comment: Поправьте ваш вопрос и добавьте код текстом, а не картинкой, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечать также картинкой? :) В следующий раз публикуйте код, тогда можно будет внести изменения в ваш код

Если схематично:
вместо цикла

```
$.each(
   $.ajax(...)
)
```

запрашивайте следующую картинку только после получения предыдущей

```
function getNext(){
  if (typeof msg !== 'undefined' && msg.length > 0)
  $.ajax(...
          success: function(){msg.shift();getNext();}
  )
}
```